# The most efficient algorithm for finding the highest valid number for an API

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I have many API endpoints that take IDs that are constantly increasing. I want an algorithm to find the highest number in the least amount of requests. I need to do this without knowing what the previous highest number was. I am thinking something like binary search would work but would it be the most efficient? I also don't know what the maximum would be.

Comment: You need a way to tell valid from invalid. If *maximum valid* increases during search, the result may be a value that was true at a point in time between request and result.

Comment: Valid will return 200 http response and invalid will return a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the set of valid IDs is either the empty set, or a set of consecutive integers starting with 1. Let D = the largest valid ID if there are any valid IDs, and D = 0 otherwise. If $2^k ≤ D < 2{k+1}$ then the following algorithm will find D using **1.5k or fewer tests** whether some d is a valid ID if D ≥ 32, and in 7 steps if 0 ≤ D < 32:

1. Let j = 6. As long as $2^j$ is a valid ID increase j by 2.
2. If j = 6 then 0 ≤ D < 64, and then we will find D using binary search using 6 tests, for a total of 7 tests. This is less than 1.5k if k ≥ 5 or D ≥ 32 and equal to 7 if D < 32.
3. If j ≥ 8 then we know that $2^{j-2} ≤ D < 2^j$, and we have performed (j - 4) / 2 tests. We check the ID $2^{j-1}$. If $2^{j-1}$ is not a valid ID, then $2^{j-2} ≤ D < 2^{j-1}$ and we find D using binary search with j-2 further tests, for a total of (j - 4) / 2 + 1 + j-2 tests. Since k = j-2, this is (k - 2) / 2 + 1 + k = 1.5k tests.
4. If $2^{j-1}$ is a valid ID, then $2^{j-1} ≤ D < 2^k$ and we find D using binary search with j-1 further tests, for a total of (j - 4) / 2 + 1 + j-1 tests. Since k = j-1, this is (k - 3) / 2 + 1 + k = 1.5k - 0.5 tests.

You may instead use the sequence j = 11, 14, 17, 20 ... and you can find D with 4k/3 tests if D ≥ 512, and 11 tests if 0 ≤ D < 512 (this requires testing $2^{11}$, then $2^9$, so not quite binary search). You could reduce the constant factor further, at the expense of higher cost for a larger range of small D's.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $1$ is always a valid ID, you can solve your problem in about $2 \log v$ queries where $v$ is the maximum value by using exponential search and binary search.

Query the API using powers of two ($2,4,8,\dots$) until you find the smallest power of two $x$ such that $x > v$. Clearly $x \le 2v$.
This requires up to $1+\lceil \log_2(v) \rceil$ queries.

Then use binary search in the range $[v-1, 2v)$ to find the exact value for $v$. This requires at most $\lceil \log_2(1+v) \rceil$ queries.

Comment: You could query using powers of four (4, 16, 64 etc. ) so you halve the number of queries until you find an upper bound, at the expense of one additional comparison in the binary search.

Answer (score 1):

If the highest valid ID d is known to be in the range $n ≤ d < n+2^k$ then binary search will determine d in k steps.

Assuming d = 1 is known to be a valid ID: You lookup ID $2^k + 1$ for some k. If this ID is invalid you know the largest valid ID is in the range $1 ≤ d ≤ 2^k$ and can be found in k steps, plus the initial lookup.

If $2^k + 1$ is valid, then you lookup ID $1 + 2^k + 2^{k'}$ for some k'. If invalid, you find d in a total of k' + 2 steps. If valid, you lookup ID $1 + 2^k + 2^{k'} + 2^{k''}$ etc.

Since you don't know d, you don't know what the optimal choices for k, k', k'' etc. are. You can choose 1, 2, 3 ..., or 2, 4, 6 ... for example. But you may be able to make an educated guess. For example, if your API processes one million IDs per day and is supposed to run for a few years, then you could start with k = 30.

If you assume that the correct value is distributed along some exponential scale, remember that nobody forces you to use binary search. You could for example aim to have ranges of size 3 * 2^k, and instead of binary search your first guess splits the range into subranges of size 2^k and 2*2^k.